Where is Bolvar?
In Grim Dawn (PC via Steam), I'm trying to do the "Cripple the Cult" quest for the Kymon's Chosen faction. There are two objectives: kill Zaria, and kill Bolvar.
I'm trying to kill Bolvar first, in the Blood Grove. The quest flavor text says:

Two of the cult's prominent members, Bolvar the Bloodbinder and Zaria the Carver, have been spotted in the Blood Grove and near the village of Darkvale.

I know Bolvar is the one in Blood Grove, but I just can't find him.
According to the fandom wiki, he spawns in 4 locations:

However, he's not in any of these locations.
According to the GrimTools map, he spawns in three locations, two of which agree with the fandom wiki map and the last of which is due south of the shrine.
He's not there either in my game.

At this point I'm just wandering in circles and I just can't find him. I've pretty much cleared the entire area at this point. Where else does Bolvar spawn?

Well, this video has him literally straight north of your position in the final screenshot, on the right side of the path that goes left-right.

Yeah that's one of the three circled locations on the map from the wiki -- he's not in any of them.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Oh, so it needs to be quite far from a marked spot. And reloading the game doesn't help either of course... May you find him~!

Yeah I tried dying, teleporting away/back, even finishing the main quest line. At this point I'm just going to give up and cross my fingers for NG+...

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Well, I can't figure out where this is, so maybe that's it? https://youtu.be/Xbv_ySdotYg?t=348

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Did you find Bolvar, or go for NG+? In either case, can you tell me where the Bolvar is in the YouTube video above?
